# Steps to deploy to an ec2 instance using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

What are the steps to deploy to an ec2 instance using Jenkins.

I am new to this field and completely confused.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need the CodeDeploy Jenkinis Plugin to orchestrate deployment using CodeDeploy from a Jenkins project:

- https://plugins.jenkins.io/codedeploy

We have a recent blog post on this:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-a-ci-cd-pipeline-by-integrating-jenkins-with-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codedeploy/

There is another blog post on same subject but it was written in 2015 so I am not sure if all steps are still relevant:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/setting-up-the-jenkins-plugin-for-aws-codedeploy/